# Access to in-place archives via MS-Graph shows the normal mailbox

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I want to get list of folders/emails inside In-Place Mailboxes as described in other posts.

Unfortunately, this proposal doesn't work in v1.0 or in beta. With *archivemsgfolderroot* only the root node of the normal user mailbox is displayed and not the in-place archive.

Request

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/archivemsgfolderroot/childFolders
```

gives exactly the same result as

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/
```

What have I overlooked? Do we need special API permissions for the In-Place Archive?

Access to the In-Place Mailbox via ExchangeWebService works fine, so for me it looks like an "MS Graph problem".